# iOS - UIWebView - Pausing javascript to run till view controller appears

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I'm creating iOS app that resembles a book. This app is based on HTML pages.
Each HTML page has javascript that will be run in onLoad() method and some part of javascript is being called usign script tag
For showing html page, i'm creating uiwebview and loading html content into it. Its working fine till here. 
In order to increase the rendering speed of a page, i'm creating a queue of 5 view controllers (with webviews) and loading content into it.
The problem here is that, javascirpt wont be executed if the webview is not visible. 
Even after view controller appears, the javascript wont be executed.
How to load only javascript when the view controller appears. Any solution there?
Hope I tried to explained the problem in better way.